# Ubuntu SSD Disk gets slow

Tags: ubuntu, ssd

I have a new PC with a Samsung SSD830 with 256GB and installed Ubuntu 12 two weeks ago.

I checked the **disk alignment**, but that was correct.

From the first day it gets slower after a while of usage.

I see it at the build time of my project or with

`dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/output bs=8k count=10k;` I get after booting 400MB/s write speed, and when I feel it is slow it is around 1.5MB/s.

When I reboot the PC, it is fast again. Is it a hardware failure? Are there any other suggestions what I can try? (tried sync command when it was slow)

EDIT: I activated auto trim as well, and did a manual trim what did not help

`UUID=7b198f7a-d783-4ff3-97a0-b06186d0bb8e /               ext4    noatime,nodiratime,discard,errors=remount-ro 0       1
UUID=8d937ac8-8286-4bf8-984d-69836d30ee88 none            swap    sw              0       0
tmpfs /tmp tmpfs defaults,noatime,mode=1777 0 0`

I thought it may be the **home directory encryption**, but without it is still getting slow.

I looked with **iotop** while he was writing but only the `dd` command was shown

`syslog` contained no sda, `dmesg` output was

```
[    0.907090] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 500118192 512-byte logical blocks: (256 GB/238 GiB)
[    0.907137] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[    0.907138] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[    0.907146] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    0.907732]  sda: sda1 sda2 < sda5 >
[    0.908058] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[    0.969494] EXT4-fs (sda1): INFO: recovery required on readonly filesystem
[    0.969499] EXT4-fs (sda1): write access will be enabled during recovery
[    1.580308] EXT4-fs (sda1): recovery complete
[    1.581925] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    1.696890] Adding 16737276k swap on /dev/sda5.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:16737276k SS
[    1.957517] EXT4-fs (sda1): re-mounted. Opts: discard,errors=remount-ro
```

Comment: It is possible that you may need to [enable TRIM](http://askubuntu.com/questions/18903/how-to-enable-trim).

Answer (score 1):

I suspect other processes are generating a lot of I/O that may cause it appear to run slow. A few things you can check in order to find that out:

- Install `iotop` and check if other processes are generating a lot of I/O. Alternatively, install `sysstat` and run `iostat -kxdN 1` to see what the load of the block devices is.
- Check if your pc runs out of memory and starts swapping. Use `top` or other system monitoring tool to check your memory usage.

To check for hardware or driver failures, inspect `dmesg` and `/var/log/syslog` for entries about your device (for example `sda`). It may be hitting SATA bus errors or similar that may cause it to jump to a lower link speed.

Comment: iotop showed only the dd command with its 2MB/s :/

Answer (score 1):

Use preload to predict what programs will be most used

To install preload on Ubuntu, Linux Mint or debian based distributions

```
# apt-get update && apt-get install preload
```

Adjust swapiness if you have enough ram to make sure swap will not be used

To change swappiness setting:

```
$ su -
# nano /etc/sysctl.conf
```

And add this line into sysctl.conf file.

```
vm.swappiness = 10
```

There are more tips from this page that I found http://namhuy.net/1563/how-to-tweak-and-optimize-ssd-for-ubuntu-linux-mint.html